# Using object outside class

Tags: c++, class, sfml

I'm trying to create some classes containing textures&sprites using SFML.
When I create object of class in SFML library in my class - i cannot use that object in main.
I wonder how to display sprite in main (e.g.):

```
class MainMenu
{
   public:
      int DrawMenu(){
         sf::Texture texture;
         if (!texture.loadFromFile("idle.png"))
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
         sf::Sprite spritemenu(texture);
         return 0;
      }

};

int main()
{
   // Create the main window
   sf::RenderWindow app(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window");

   // Load a sprite to display
   sf::Texture texture;
   if (!texture.loadFromFile("cb.bmp"))
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   sf::Sprite sprite(texture);

   MainMenu menu;
   // Start the game loop
   while (app.isOpen())
   {
      // Process events
      sf::Event event;
      while (app.pollEvent(event))
      {
         // Close window : exit
         if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            app.close();
      }

      // Clear screen
      app.clear();

      // Draw the sprite
      app.draw(sprite);

      menu.DrawMenu();
      app.draw(spritemenu);

      // Update the window
      app.display();
   }

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Remember that when DrawMenu finishes the local variables go out of scope. Maybe you want class member variables instead of local variables (so they exist after DrawMenu finishes)?

Comment: yes, sure. how to make it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `DrawMenu` function name is **lying**. It doesn't *draw* anything. It loads the texture and sprite.

`DrawMenu` should simply *draw* the menu sprite:

```
void DrawMenu(sf::RenderWindow& window) { // window = where to draw the menu
   window.draw(spritemenu);
}
```

Now where do you load `spritemenu`? It stays the same through the lifetime of `MainMenu`, so it should naturally be instantiated in the *constructor* of `MainMenu`:

```
class MainMenu
{
   public:
      MainMenu() {
         if (!texture.loadFromFile("cb.bmp"))
            abort(); // or throw exception
         spritemenu.setTexture(texture); // "initialize" spritemenu with texture
      }
   …
   private:
      sf::Texture texture;   // Store these as member data, so they will be
      sf::Sprite spritemenu; // kept alive through the lifetime of MainMenu.
};
```

Now when you do `MainMenu menu;` the texture and sprite will be initialized **once**, and not every time you call the draw function.

And when you need to draw the `menu`, simply call `menu.DrawMenu(app);` instead of `menu.DrawMenu(); app.draw(spritemenu);`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is probably to pass `app` as an argument to `DrawMenu`, something like this:

```
class MainMenu {
public:
    int DrawMenu(sf::RenderWindow& app){
        sf::Texture texture;
        if(!texture.loadFromFile("idle.png"))
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        sf::Sprite spritemenu(texture);
        app.draw(spritemenu);
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Then call `menu.DrawMenu(app)` instead of `menu.DrawMenu()`.

---

Note that it's meaningless to return `EXIT_FAILURE` from any function other than `main()`; I suggest throwing an exception instead.

Also, it's silly to reload the menu every time you draw it. I suggest moving the loading to the MainMenu constructor.

Comment: Note your code won't compile because you are returning an `int` from a `void` function (I'd fix it but unsure whether you deliberately chose a `void` return to back up your point about throwing an exception)

Comment: Initially I had changed the code to support the two additional comments. Then I changed my mind, but forgot to put the return type back.